# Flutter | want to add a favorited item to an already created list or a list that is to be created

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, riverpod

I'm trying to implement a feature that is to add a selected item to a selected list that users create. I want end user either create a new list to add this item or select a list which user had created prior.

[UI for a question item where a user can click on star icon.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVRxo.png)

The code for this;

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Question> getNewListofQuestions = List.of(widget.questions);
    getNewListofQuestions.shuffle();
    var currentQuestion = getNewListofQuestions[currentQuestionIndex];


    void onCreateNewList(CreatedList newestList) {
      ref
          .watch(createdListsProvider.notifier)
          .toggleCreatedListsStatus(newestList);
    }

    final favoriteQuestions = ref.watch(favoriteQuestionsProvider);
    final isFavorite = favoriteQuestions.contains(currentQuestion);

    void openAddNewListOverlay() {
      if (isFavorite) {
        // createdLists[index]
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).clearSnackBars();
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
            content: Text(
              'Question removed from all your lists.',
            ),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        showModalBottomSheet(
          shape: const BeveledRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
              topRight: Radius.circular(10),
            ),
          ),
          isScrollControlled: true,
          useSafeArea: true,
          context: context,
          builder: (ctx) => QuestionsOverlayItem(onCreateList: onCreateNewList),
        );
      }
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (ctx) => const TabsScreen(),
                ),
              );
            },
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back_sharp,
              color: Colors.white70,
              size: 40.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(currentQuestion.question),
            Text(
              currentQuestion.intensity.name[0].toUpperCase() +
                  currentQuestion.intensity.name.substring(1),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed:
                  
                      openAddNewListOverlay,
                  icon: Icon(
                    isFavorite ? Icons.star_rounded : Icons.star_border_rounded,
                    size: 40,
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.send_rounded,
                    size: 30,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

[UI for the overlay  modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLvPn.png)

Since i use the lists app-wide i created  below Riverpod provider file for list creation.

```
class CreatedListsNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<CreatedList>> {
  CreatedListsNotifier() : super([]);

  bool toggleCreatedListsStatus(CreatedList newestList) {
    final alreadyCreatedList = state.contains(newestList);

    if (alreadyCreatedList) {
      state = state.where((L) => L.title != newestList.title).toList();
      return false;
    } else {
      state = [...state, newestList];
      return true;
    }
  }

  void onDismissListItem(CreatedList item, WidgetRef ref) {
    final latestList = ref.read(createdListsProvider);

    if (latestList.contains(item)) {
      state = state
          .where((indexeditem) => indexeditem.title != item.title)
          .toList();
    }
  }
}

final createdListsProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<CreatedListsNotifier, List<CreatedList>>((ref) {
  return CreatedListsNotifier();
});
```

I'm able to save the item to a list with riverpod but not able to do it to the selected list. I also created a provider file for favoriting questions however stuck in a place where i can’t manage to connect the currentquestion to move to the selected list inside createdListsProvider. I tried riverpod documentation to find the solution however can’t create solution. I would appriciate any support.